# Building OpenCV 3.2.0 with MinGW-w64 6.1.0: compile-time argument evaluation faiIure

Tags: c++, opencv, build, constexpr, compile-time-constant

The compiler fails with this output:

```
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/include/emmintrin.h:31:0,
                 from C:/lib/opencv/sources/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:168,
                 from C:/lib/opencv/sources/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52,
                 from C:/lib/opencv/sources/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:56,
                 from C:/lib/opencv/sources/cmake-build-debug/modules/core/precomp.hpp:49:

C:/lib/opencv/sources/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/sse_utils.hpp: 
    In function 'void _mm_interleave_ps(__m128&, __m128&, __m128&, __m128&)':
C:/lib/opencv/sources/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/sse_utils.hpp:572:28: 
    error: the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate
    __m128 layer2_chunk0 = _mm_shuffle_ps(v_r0, v_r1, mask_lo);
                           ^
```

At this function:

```
inline void _mm_interleave_ps(__m128 & v_r0, __m128 & v_r1, __m128 & v_g0, __m128 & v_g1)
{
    const int mask_lo = _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0), mask_hi = _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 3, 1);
    __m128 layer2_chunk0 = _mm_shuffle_ps(v_r0, v_r1, mask_lo);
...
```

Considering `_MM_SHUFFLE` is a macro, the masks should be compile-time calculable:

```
#define _MM_SHUFFLE(fp3,fp2,fp1,fp0) \
    (((fp3) << 6) | ((fp2) << 4) | ((fp1) << 2) | (fp0))
```

So I tried to replace `const int ...` with `constexpr int ...`, but it gave no effect.

The only workaround I found is [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/98913/building-opencv-with-mingw-builds-gcc-610-x86_64-win32-seh/), but it does not answer why the masks are not immediates, and why threads can affect this.

Any way to fix this more or less decently except for hardcoding `0x88` and `0xDD` like `_mm_shuffle_ps(v_r0, v_r1, 0x88)`?
It does work, but obviously is not a good solution. Moreover, this file is not the only one having this issue.

Also, why is not even `constexpr int mask_lo = 0x88` considered an immediate?