# How to build OpenCV 3.2.0 with MinGW on Windows

Tags: windows, opencv, build, cmake, mingw

This post contains all the problems I (and other users) had while building the library from sources. As there is no tutorial, I decided to create this sort of FAQ post to put all the solutions together. Hope it will help!

Configuration:
OpenCV 3.2.0
MinGW-w64 x86_64-6.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0

You are welcome to add more information in the answers, as it is more handy to have everything in one place.

Comment: WOW wonderful!! Do you know how to use `dlib` with OpenCV in python for Windows environment?

Comment: This could be fine for StackOver Documentation, but it not a valid question.

Comment: @usr1234567 it was intended to be a Q&A question. I think it needs some better solutions for errors 3 and 4 to be a doc

Comment: @JeruLuke, unfortunatelly, I don't

Comment: @Alex Perhaps you can document this answer in the **Documentation** section. Such content must not go to waste

Comment: @JeruLuke, as far as I know, the question is just going to be closed, not deleted. I will probably move it to the Documentation as soon as the solutions it offers get good enough. Docs are for docs :)

Answer (score 6):

1. Download and unpack OpenCV to a folder of your choice.
2. `opencv\sources` now contains `CMakeLists.txt` and all the other files necessary. Configure the project in CMake. CLion users may just open `CMakeLists.txt`.

   - **Fix 1**: `sprintf ()` family security error.
     Add `add_definitions(-DSTRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE)` to the beginning of `CMakeLists.txt`. This will define `STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE` symbol for the project and suppress the error.
   - **Fix 2**: 'too many sections' `as.exe` error.
     Add the following lines to the beginning of `CMakeLists.txt` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31907912)):

     ```
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-Wa,-mbig-obj")
     set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} "-Wa,-mbig-obj")
     ```
   - **Fix 3**: 'the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate'.
     Found nothing better than hardcoding `0x88` instead of `mask_lo = _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0)` (binary `10 00 10 00`) and `0xDD` instead of `mask_hi`.
     As soon as [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41913252/4769035) gets a better answer, I will update this paragraph.
   - **Fix 4**: no c++11 `thread`s in MinGW.
     Again, a dirty solution: added `#include <mingw.*.h>` to `<mutex>`, `<thread>`, `<condition_variable>` before `#endif // C++11`. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421968))
3. Build it! It will take about 30-40 minutes.
4. Find the output folder. It is still a mess but contains a `Makefile`.
   Launch `cmd`, `cd` to the output folder and call `[path to compiler]\mingw32-make.exe install`. ([Source](http://answers.opencv.org/question/122696/is-it-possible-to-build-opencv-320-libraries-using-mingw-for-a-32bit-windows/))
5. Voila, your library is in the `install` folder! Now you can move it to a desired destination and set up environment variables.

Comment: how to solve this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930349/opencv-installation-error-while-mingw32-make-on-windows